# Images in python using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Can't make this image to display. I get an error saying `TclError: image "pyimage21" doesn't exist`
Here is what I tried

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("500x500")

root.title("Poker ranges")

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\chaeh\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\poker\\hand_range_grid.png")
text = tk.Label(root,image = photo)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error suggests you’ve opened more than one image file and maybe that you’ve created more than one instance of `Tk`. Does this exact code and only this code give this exact error?

Comment: Maybe you're using double slash instead of single slash. My drive is like this C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\python3.12\bouncing_ball

Comment: @toyotaSupra: if the problem was with the path to the file there would be a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to pack, grid or place your label...
2. I suggest to use pathlib to find correct path, because tkinter need relative references to use images...

[image: Example]

```py
import pathlib
import tkinter as tk

DIR = pathlib.Path('.')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Poker ranges")

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=DIR / "abc.png")
text = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```